# Splitting rows in Pandas based on column values and mapping column names

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with two columns Person Name and Company Name. I want to create two more columns called Name and Name_Type. Name would be concat of Person and Company Name and Name_Type column would determine if the name is Person type or Company type. Some rows have empty strings, which creates four possibilities:

1) Empty Person + Empty Company = Can be left blank.

2) Empty Person + Company Name = Company Name Value

3) Person Name + Empty Person = Person Name Value

4) Both Name = Split them into two rows. Cannot figure out how to do that.

I am a Python and Pandas beginner, I haven't come across an answer online. Hoping to find something here. Please excuse format or other errors.

Input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Person_name": ["Aaron", "", "Phil", "Joe"], 
                  "Company_name": ["", "XYZ Inc", "ABC LLC", ""]})

    Company_name    Person_name
0                   Aaron
1   XYZ Inc 
2   ABC LLC         Phil
3                   Joe
```

Expected output:

```
    Company_name    Person_name Name    Name_Type
0                   Aaron       Aaron   Person_name
1   XYZ Inc                     XYZ Inc Company_name
2   ABC LLC         Phil        Phil    Person_name
2   ABC LLC         Phil        ABC LLC Company_name
3                   Joe         Joe     Person_name
```

Comment: Post a sample input/output

Comment: Can you produce a [MCVE]?

Comment: @RafaelC Please take a look at the sample image

Comment: @HarvIpan Please take a look at the sample image

Comment: No images but code/ text that we can copy and paste, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `apply`, `unstack` and `merge`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Person_name": ["Aaron", "", "Phil", "Joe"], 
                  "Company_name": ["", "XYZ Inc", "ABC LLC", ""]})

def logic(row):
    if row.Company_name and row.Person_name:
        return pd.Series([[row.Person_name, "Person_name"], [row.Company_name, "Company_name"]])
    else:
        return pd.Series([[row.Person_name, "Person_name"] if row.Person_name else [row.Company_name, "Company_name"]])
df2 = df.apply(logic, 1).unstack().apply(pd.Series).dropna().reset_index().set_index("level_1").sort_index()
dff = pd.merge(df,df2, left_index=True, right_index=True).iloc[:, [0,1,3,4]]
dff.columns = ["Company_name", "Person_name", "Name", "Name_Type"]
```

Output

```
    Company_name    Person_name Name    Name_Type
0                   Aaron       Aaron   Person_name
1   XYZ Inc                     XYZ Inc Company_name
2   ABC LLC         Phil        Phil    Person_name
2   ABC LLC         Phil        ABC LLC Company_name
3                   Joe         Joe     Person_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
(df1.melt('index', var_name='Name_Type', value_name='Name')
   .replace('',np.nan).dropna()
   .merge(df1, on='index').sort_values('index')
   .set_index('index'))
```

Output:

```
          Name_Type     Name Person_name Company_name
index                                                
0       Person_name    Aaron       Aaron             
1      Company_name  XYZ Inc                  XYZ Inc
2       Person_name     Phil        Phil      ABC LLC
2      Company_name  ABC LLC        Phil      ABC LLC
3       Person_name      Joe         Joe
```